# Is drawing on HTML5 Canvas supported in IE9 for Windows Phone 7.5?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, canvas

Is drawing on HTML5 Canvas supported in IE9 for Windows Phone 7.5?

The code I'm using works for iOS, Android, webkit browsers, Firefox, Opera and IE9 but not for Windows Phone for some reason?  I saw somewhere that Windows Phone IE9 supported canvas (which I guess technically is true because the canvas shows up in the phone's browser) but you can't draw on it using touch events.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////
//start mouse canvas drawn signature script
////////////////////////////////////////////
var canvasToHide;
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

sigCanvas = document.getElementById('signatureCanvas');
var context = sigCanvas.getContext('2d');
context.strokeStyle = '#00f'; // blue

if (is_touch_device) {

    // get the canvas element and its context

    // create a drawer which tracks touch movements
    var drawer = {
        isDrawing: false,
        touchstart: function (coors) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(coors.x, coors.y);
            this.isDrawing = true;
        },
        touchmove: function (coors) {
            if (this.isDrawing) {
                context.lineTo(coors.x, coors.y);
                context.stroke();
            }
        },
        touchend: function (coors) {
            if (this.isDrawing) {
                this.touchmove(coors);
                this.isDrawing = false;
            }
        }
    };

    // create a function to pass touch events and coordinates to drawer
    function draw(event) {
        // get the touch coordinates
        var coors = {
            x: event.targetTouches[0].pageX - 100,
            y: event.targetTouches[0].pageY - 100
        };
        // pass the coordinates to the appropriate handler
        drawer[event.type](coors);
    }

    // attach the touchstart, touchmove, touchend event listeners.
    sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchstart', draw, false);
    sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw, false);
    sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchend', draw, false);

    // prevent elastic scrolling
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false); // end body.onTouchMove

} else {

    var bMouseIsDown = false;

    var iWidth = sigCanvas.width;
    var iHeight = sigCanvas.height;

    sigCanvas.onmousedown = function (e) {
        bMouseIsDown = true;
        iLastX = e.clientX - 100 + sigCanvas.offsetLeft + (window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft);
        iLastY = e.clientY - 100 + sigCanvas.offsetTop + (window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    }

    sigCanvas.onmouseup = function () {
        bMouseIsDown = false;
        iLastX = -1;
        iLastY = -1;
    }

    sigCanvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        if (bMouseIsDown) {
            var iX = e.clientX - 100 + sigCanvas.offsetLeft + (window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft);
            var iY = e.clientY - 100 + sigCanvas.offsetTop + (window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
            context.moveTo(iLastX, iLastY);
            context.lineTo(iX, iY);
            context.stroke();
            iLastX = iX;
            iLastY = iY;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IE on WP 7.5 does support canvas, but doesn't support the touch api. Just checked it on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

WP7 and WP7.5 Mango at the time of writing **does not** [support touch* events](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2011/05/24/Internet-Explorer-Mobile-9-is-DOA-Without-Touch-Support.aspx), nor does it support the desktop-standard [mousemove event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/7d532167-c26d-472f-8994-346f8fc9f840), as it interprets any swipe or touch move (except tapping) of the fingers a gesture, and prevents any mouse events from being fired.

This, at the moment, makes it impossible to code any sophisticated touch UI (like the drawing app you mentioned) for the Internet Explorer browser found in Windows Phones.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function report(ch) {
var div = document.getElementById('debug');
div.innerHTML += ch;
}
function myready() {
var el = document.getElementById('grid');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle='#ff0000';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
el.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {report('D')});
el.addEventListener("mousemove", function (evt) {report('M')});
el.addEventListener("mouseup", function (evt) {report('U')});        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload='myready()'>
<canvas id="grid" width='400' height='60'></canvas>
<div id='debug'>+</div>
</body>

</html>
```